# Composite aggregation query with bucket_sort does not work properly

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have an index to store financial transactions:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "amount": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "currencyCode": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "merchantId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "merchantName": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "partnerId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "transactionDate": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "userId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my query:

```
GET /transactions/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "date_merchant": {
      "aggs": {
        "amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        },
        "amount_sort": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "amount": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "top_hit": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "merchantName",
                "currencyCode"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      },
      "composite": {
        "size": 1,
        "sources": [
          {
            "date": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "calendar_interval": "day",
                "field": "transactionDate"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "merchant": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "merchantId"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "userId": "AAA"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "partnerId": "BBB"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "transactionDate": {
              "gte": "2022-07-01"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "currencyCode": "EUR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

Please note the `"size": 1` in the composite aggregation.

If I change it to `3` (based on my data)... I get different results!

That means the bucket_sort operation doesn't work on the whole list of buckets, but just on the returned ones (if it's just one, that means it's not going to be sorted at all!)

How can I sort on ALL the buckets instead?

**EDIT**

Based on Benjamin's answer I changed my query to use normal aggregations instead of composite, and a large bucket size for merchant IDs (default is 10, while for date histogram there's no limit)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Composite agg design

The composite aggregation is designed to iterate all buckets in the most efficient way possible.

> How can I sort on ALL the buckets instead?

To fully sort over ALL buckets, all buckets would have to be enumerated ahead of time, defeating the design of the composite aggregation.

### So, how to actually sort over all buckets?

Then aggregate over all buckets in a single call. Set your size to the largest number of buckets available within your query.

The number of buckets will be the cardinality of `merchantId` and the number of days in the date histogram.

Another option is to paginate over all the composite buckets and then sort them client side. If you choose this path, it may be good to have each page of the composite aggregation be sorted so that sorting them client side will be faster.

Comment: Please check my answer, too. How can I paginate w/o composite aggs?

Comment: @FabioB. seems you misunderstood my answer. I am saying you should use composite, but set the page size very large to capture all the buckets in a single page. This way the sort occurs over all the elements. Also, you cannot paginate within aggs while expecting fully sorted results when sorting over an aggregated field. Its the tradeoff of paginating via composite aggregation.

Comment: I understood. I decided to give up composite aggregation. I edited my question to show the query I'm using instead. Due to the cardinality of my data, I can handle pagination and sorting on client side. I just need ALL the buckets reliably returned to me. Thanks